# make a bin lazy load in macvim

Tags: bash, shell, vim, zsh, macvim

Im using `oh-my-zsh` with the `zsh-nvm` plugin.

The huge benefit is if I set `NVM_LAZY_LOAD=true`, it wont take 1 second to load node/nvm in my terminal every time I make a new terminal tab. Instead it loads lazily if I type a certain command, which I must add to a list of:

**.zshrc**

```
export NVM_LAZY_LOAD_EXTRA_COMMANDS=('create-vue' 'eslint' 'v' 'wrangler' 'yarn')
```

The code for it is here:

https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm/blob/23067bd9bb6eb6f4737a3ea90cb0cb5e85f61ba2/zsh-nvm.plugin.zsh#L80

I have a custom script `v` to start MacVim (vim for osx) from the current `.` folder that my terminal is viewing.

**.zsh/bin/v**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec mvim "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1

exit $?
```

Question: This might be a stretch, but is there a way I can defer the lazy loading INTO macvim's access of zsh shell (when eslint runs inside macvim first time)? So that inside vim that is when it would lazy load the first time I run the command (that way every time I start vim it doesnt take like 1 second now before it opens)

Comment: It's `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Wow, I didnt even notice that. This is from 10 years ago so I probably typo'd it then and its just lived there ever since

Comment: It doesnt fix the issue, but im glad you pointed that out. thanks

Comment: YMMV using `mvim $@` instead of `mvim "$@"`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Regarding `If I try to add v to the list of lazy load commands, it wont load, presumably because its a shell script.` - `v` is not a shell script, it's an alias. It probably WOULD load if it was a shell script (or maybe even a function)? I've never heard of `NVM_LAZY_LOAD_EXTRA_COMMANDS`, though, and I'm unfamiliar with what you're doing so I'm just guessing and you'd have to check the manual for that to see what it can include.

Comment: @EdMorton i see what youre saying, that makes sense. I suppose I can rename it v.sh and source it manually from zshrc or something so it gets added to my path?

Comment: If you put `v.sh` (but btw - shell commands should really not end in `.sh` or any other suffix so it should really just be named `v`) in your `~/bin` or any other directory in your `PATH` then that might be all you need for whatever uses `NVM_LAZY_LOAD_EXTRA_COMMANDS` to pick it up.

Comment: awesome thanks, and also thanks for reminding me, I will do +x and not use sh extension. It has been very long time since I did all this

Comment: @EdMorton awesome, making it an actual bash script fixed it. thanks! Do you know off hand if its possible to get it deferred into vim now?

Comment: I've never heard of any of the software you're using (apart from `bash`) and have no idea what it does or how it works, sorry.